# Why does mounted drive show a "prohibited" sign?

Tags: mount, nautilus, fstab, gnome-disk-utility

I have mounted an internal hdd in 18.04 using the gnome-disks utility, selecting "mount at system statup". 
In nautilus the drive shows up with a "prohibited" sign like this.

[image: upper left corner of nautilus]

I have not noticed any other issues.
fstab looks like this

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/9d73bb1e-9411-4679-ac77-95c193b558ac /media/username/snurre auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=snurre,x-gvfs-icon=snurre,x-gvfs-symbolic-icon=snurre 0 0

Any idea what this is supposed to indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just ask somebody and you'll figure it out yourself! :-D

Just omit the `x-gvfs-icon` and `x-gvfs-symbolic-icon` from the mount options and you will get a sensible default.

[image: nautilus upper left corner]

---

Edit:
Here are the mount options from gnome-disks with the **Icon Name** and **Symbolic Icon Name** options. I guess you could do some cool tweaks with these if you wanted to :-)

[image]

Comment: Nice find. I never heard of these options. Apparently you didn't put them in yourself?

Comment: Nope. They are from the gnome-disks utility. Screenshot added.